# `git log` shows notes that `git notes` doesn't

Tags: git, git-notes

I'm using [stepup](https://github.com/kawamanza/step-up) to manage git notes that are used to automate version numbering and release notes.

The notes in one of our repos seem to be messed up:

```
$ git log HEAD

commit 04c85f5ad7e5d60de8c9f0b8e08681e833751909
Author: Daniel Serodio <dserodio@i.dont.like.spam>
Date:   Wed Oct 29 15:47:55 2014 -0200

    non-deps removed

Notes (added):
    splittest beta
```

However:

```
$ git notes show HEAD

error: No note found for object 04c85f5ad7e5d60de8c9f0b8e08681e833751909.
```

Does anyone have a clue about the cause and/or the fix for this?

Answer (score 4):

`git log` respects the configuration entry notes.displayRef which I am guessing you have to set to either '*' or 'added'

To make `git notes` show it try

```
git notes --ref=added show HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

> `git log` respects the configuration entry `notes.displayRef`

Indeed. Make sure to *not* set it to an *empty* value in your test, or it would segfault (before Git 2.30 (Q1 2021))

The Config parser has been fixed for `git notes`.

See [commit 45fef15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45fef1599af19404a7d0d80a985b303d665ef4a3), [commit c3eb95a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3eb95a0d759d80d53ccb396627c400cd3db6e6d) (22 Nov 2020) by [Nate Avers (`nateavers`)](https://github.com/nateavers).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e082a85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e082a85708e70a04bbdd8fbb23ad81643b7be280), 30 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`notes.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3eb95a0d759d80d53ccb396627c400cd3db6e6d): fix a segfault in `notes_display_config()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Nate Avers</sup>

> If `notes.displayRef` is configured with no value<sup>`[1]`</sup>, control should be returned to the caller when [`notes.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c3eb95a0d759d80d53ccb396627c400cd3db6e6d/notes.c)`:notes_display_config()` checks if '`v`' is `NULL`.
> Otherwise, both [`git log --notes`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c3eb95a0d759d80d53ccb396627c400cd3db6e6d/Documentation/pretty-options.txt#L60)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---notesltrefgt))</sup> and [`git diff-tree --notes`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c3eb95a0d759d80d53ccb396627c400cd3db6e6d/Documentation/pretty-options.txt#L60)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt---notesltrefgt))</sup> will subsequently segfault when [`refs.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c3eb95a0d759d80d53ccb396627c400cd3db6e6d/refs.h)`:has_glob_specials()` calls `strpbrk()` with a `NULL` first argument.
>
> <sup>`[1]`</sup> Examples:
>
> ```
> .git/config:
> [notes]
>   displayRef
>
> $ git -c notes.displayRef [...]
> ```